# What's happening to an int that starts with 0? ex 00101

Tags: c++

I am wondering, what is happening when an int is starting with a zero?

```
int main() {
    int myint = 01001;
    cout << myint;
    return 0;
}
```

Why is that outputting:

```
513
```

I have tried several compilers.

Comment: Why do you need a leading zero in your `int`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Then the integer is treated as an octal number. So,

```
01001
```

equals

```
1 * 8 ^ 0 + 0 * 8 ^ 1 + 0 * 8 ^ 2 + 1 * 8 ^ 3 = 1 + 0 + 0 + 512 = 513
```

No magic in there.

Comment: One of the more surprising corners of the language specification, one that's unfortunately shared by Python.

Comment: Yup, I just checked Python on Codepad..

Comment: @Martol1ni don't write the leading 0.

Comment: @Martol1ni, you could try `int(01001.)`. Floating point constants aren't affected by the leading zero.

Comment: @MarkRansom: You probably already know this, but for others reading: [Python 3 no longer offers octal literals with a leading zero](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#integers). They would be written with a `0o` prefix, eg. `0o1001` in Python 3.

Comment: @GregHewgill, yes I knew that - and I think it's a big mistake that they now treat leading zeros as a syntax error rather than ignoring them. But as this is a question about C++ I'm sorry I brought it up.

Comment: You can use cout << oct << myint;  That'll display it in octal, but your int still stores the decimal number 513.